# Is it real multiple thread when I create the thread in a loop

Tags: java

I try to create 10 threads in a 10-times loop, and want to see the conflicts print out when I didn't assign the synchronized on the method.
This is my code

```
public class SingletonService {

private static SingletonService singleton = null;


public static SingletonService getInstance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        synchronized(SingletonService.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new SingletonService();
                return singleton;
            }
        }
    }

    return singleton;
}

public  void testMethod() {
    boolean flag = true;
    System.out.println("start");
    if (flag == false) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Error");
    }
    flag = false;
    System.out.println("over");
}


  }
```

Below is the thread which get the service and call the testMethod()

```
public class Transferable extends Thread {

    private SingletonService service = null;

    public Transferable(SingletonService aService) {
        service = aService;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Service Start");
        service.testMethod();
        System.out.println("Service End");

    }
}
```

Now which confused me a lot is that when I try to create the thread in a loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            Transferable t1 = new Transferable(service);
            t1.run();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

then the callMethod() in the service will be executed sequencelly and will not affect each other (also the error message will not be thrown out)

But when I try to create the thread manually like

```
Transferable t1 = new Transferable(service);
Transferable t2 = new Transferable(service);
Transferable t3 = new Transferable(service);
Transferable t4 = new Transferable(service);
Transferable t5 = new Transferable(service);
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
t4.start();
t5.start();
```

The error message is printed out and the start-end sequence also become disorder...
Any one can help to solve my problem the tell the detail?
Thanks^BR

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10);` this is enough time

Comment: Do you see any difference in how you *start* your threads by hand, compared with how your loop *runs* them?

Comment: To tell the truth...I doubt that thread in loop run will only and forever execute certain one thread because every time I just point to a new thread to the t1...and JVM will force it finish the run before a new reference start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Thread java se documentation site
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html and in particular the start() method

start(): Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

Calling run() inside your loop doesn't cause the Thead to execute. In contrary, run() is executed in the main Thread and that's the reason why execution is sequential and not in parallel as you would expect.

Please try replacing run() with start() in your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that contribute to the behavior of your two examples.

First, `SingletonService.testMethod()` defines `flag` as a local variable. Thus, it cannot really be used as a flag to check thread conflicts. I don't see how you could ever get an *error* output. This flag should be a field.

Second, the looped example calls the `run()` method of the thread, while the manual example calls the `start()` method. `start()` will create a new thread which will in turn call the `run()` method. `run()` will simply execute your `Transferable.run()` method in the **current** thread, thus enforcing a sequential operation.

Third, if you were change the aforementioned things, you would still have a `Thread.sleep(10)` call in each loop, meaning that between starting one thread and the next, you wait 10 milliseconds which is more than enough time for the first thread to finish.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But why Thread.sleep(10) works when I try to create the thread 10 times manually instead of point it as a new thread ? I tried to update my source follow your advice but which still print same result

Comment: The first behavior is my mistake of the code uploading.

Comment: The reason which caused this problem is exactlly the second behavior